# Drupal6: View that shows a directory structure

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I've built a content type to handle document upload. My content type uses a Book node to handle directories/subdirectories and I would like to show a couple of Views that shows the directories structure. When clicking on a directory I would like to show, in another view, all the documents inserted in that directory.
Do you know any existing examples of Views/Panels? That shows a similar structure, as in the Windows Explorer, using Views2?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this module: [views_tree](http://drupal.org/project/views_tree)

Also tree-like can be built via argument handlers...

Comment: hello and thank you very much; i checked the views_tree; it makes what i need but i would like collapsible items, as in classic trees